# Over inflated job postings not matching day to day duties

Tags: hiring-process, position

This is the fourth company I work for and noticing a trend of really extravagant job postings  that would make you think the company is solving world hunger and cancer all on the same day and that the people who work there must be super human or The elite of the elite.

Some of the job postings are paragraphs long with  requirements for being everything all in one job.  It would seem you would need multiple  lifetimes of experience for some of these postings.

However,  once working there, what I see is a little different. It seems like it was a façade of grandiose or a little deceptive.  Not that the people aren't smart, but  duties performed see much less intense, less complex, and a little more run-of-the-mill type duties.

The question is what is the purpose for job postings like this? Why not state exactly what the job would be like?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bait-and-switch

Comment: Would you work for a company that promises regular, day-to-day drudgery, if you could work for a company that promises to solve world hunger and cancer all on the same day?

Comment: This is called marketing. They want to attract inspirational talent to their company and so need to be able to attract that talent using grandiose job statements. It's not necessarily a bait-and-switch as long as the day to day activities somewhat match the job advertisement, albeit on a much smaller scale.

Answer (score 6):

> This is the fourth company I work for and noticing a trend of really extravagant job postings that would make you think the company is solving world hunger

Question: What's the one common factor between all four jobs?

Answer: *You*

There is something in all four that attracted you to the ad and made you respond to it. I would take some time to evaluate what motivates you to respond to ads like that.

Yes these job ads need to be honest, clear and more accurate.

Still, getting a job is a long process. You had chances to ask questions, take your time, do some research, ask your personal network for advice and feel out your gut.

Read the ads, take it with a grain of salt, protect yourself by doing research but try not to always respond to the same kinds of ads.

Don't assume that the ads accurately reflect the culture of the company or the position.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, job applications and CVs are just as exaggerated... You mention everything you have ever done in any job, to increase the possibility of the experiences you offer and the ones companies are looking for matching up.

I also once had a conversation with a manager complaining that he needs 3 people, but can only hire one. So he put all requirements for 3 jobs in one posting in the hopes of finding someone who can take on as many tasks as possible. Because this dream employee never exists, they eventually hire the one they deem best suited, but in reality one person can only work so much and other tasks get delegated to different employees, or the recruiting process took so long that the requirements changed already.